# SSL Certificate for WPSE Meta invalid

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I just realised that https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/ doesn't have a proper SSL certificate set as the site kind of broke when using [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere). The main site is fine, just the meta site is affected.

The certificate served is only valid for:

> *.stackexchange.com, stackexchange.com, meta.stackexchange.com,
>   stackoverflow.com, *.stackoverflow.com, stackauth.com, sstatic.net,
>   *.sstatic.net, serverfault.com, meta.serverfault.com, superuser.com, meta.superuser.com, stackapps.com, openid.stackauth.com,
>   *.meta.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5):

At the moment, this is by design. We do not yet fully support SSL across the network, and we do not support HTTPS Everywhere.

We *intend* to support SSL, but that's still a ways out and we don't have an ETA.

Comment: Okay, good to know. But even if it is by design then I think instead of delivering an invalid certificate redirecting to http would be better, wouldn't it?

Comment: Is there an ETA on this now that Letsencrypt is introducing wildcard subdomains in January?

Comment: @TomJNowell We don't use LetsEncrypt. :) We've switched to full SSL in Q&A a few months ago. Note that meta sites now live at a different url: \*.meta.stackexchange.com because wildcards in the middle of a host address are not allowed in SSL certs.